# Skip username prompt when using git

Tags: linux, git, login

Is there a way to skip the username prompt when I `git pull`? I read about skipping the entire authentification e.g. with the help of [keys](https://superuser.com/questions/338511/how-do-i-disable-password-prompts-when-doing-git-push-pull) or [ssh agents](https://superuser.com/questions/199507/how-do-i-ensure-git-doesnt-ask-me-for-my-github-username-and-password). However, I only want to send my username. Is this somehow possible?

I contribute to a private repo a friend shared with me - if that matters. My `user.name` is written in the global git config and I use https protocol for the `remote.origin.url`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For both HTTP(S) and SSH, the username can be specified as part of the URL in `user@host` form:

- `https://user@example.com/repo.git`
- `user@example.com:repo.git`

  *(Yes, `git@github.com` means that the SSH username is always `git` when using GitHub.)*
- `ssh://user@example.com/repo.git`

If necessary, use `git remote set-url` or directly edit the `.git/config` file.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest Solution:

From your git root directory, edit the config file `.git/config`.

You should see a section that looks like the following:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://xxx.xxx/xxx/xxx.git
```

What you want to do is add your `username@` directly after the `https://`. As such:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://username@xxx.xxx/xxx/xxx.git
```

Save and close this config file, and Git will no longer prompt you for your username when within that repo.